# Java regex Matcher.end() not returning desired index

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regex in Java and wanted to write a regex to match a particular pattern and get the next index immediately after the match. I have written the following code:

```
temp = "contains(text(),\"something\")]"
String pattern = "^contains\\(text\\(\\),\"(.*)\"\\)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(temp);
if(m.find())
{   
    value = m.group(0);
    type = CONTAINS;
    pointer = m.end();
    //System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

After this, pointer goes out of range. Note that the regex pattern that I have provided ends at `)` so I expect pointer to have the index of `]` but this isn't the case. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be miscounting where you expect `]` to be.  Remember that the escaping `\`s for the quotes do not count since they vanish when the string is built.

Here's something that proves it can find the `]`

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        String temp = "contains(text(),\"something\")]";
        String pattern = "^contains\\(text\\(\\),\"(.*)\"\\)";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = r.matcher(temp);
        if(m.find())
        {   
            String value = m.group(0);
            System.out.println(value+" <-- value"); //TODO remove debugging code
//            type = CONTAINS;  //<- no idea what this was for
            int pointer = m.end();
            System.out.println(pointer+" <-- pointer"); //TODO remove debugging code

            System.out.println(m.group(1)+" <-- m.group(1)");

            System.out.println(temp.substring(pointer, pointer+1)
                +" <-- temp.substring(pointer, pointer+1)"); //TODO remove debugging code
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
contains(text(), "something") <-- value
28 <-- pointer
something <-- m.group(1)
] <-- temp.substring(pointer, pointer+1)
```

Comment: The space came while pasting here. It isnt there in my actual code. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user3138572 This what you need?

Comment: Yes. I think I was doing something else wrong. Its solved now. Thanks.